# How to send using API recurring event with a counter in the title

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-api

Is there a way to send recurring event using outlook API with a counter in the title?

For an example - let's assume it's a recurring  weekly meeting and I want it to have the titles:

"Weekly Meeting 1" in the first week

"Weekly Meeting 2" in the second week and so on...